# Make table container fill remaining viewport height but prevent window vertical scrolling (and add vertical scroll to the table)

Tags: html, css

I want to make a table fill remaining height and prevent it from making a browser vertical scroll. Instead, I want the table itself (or its container) to have vertical scroll.

I followed another post to create a div that fills remaining height: [Make a div fill the height of the remaining screen space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-screen-space)

So I tried to wrap the table in a container div and set it to 100% `max-height`, but that doesn't work:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.box .row {
  border: 2px dotted grey;
}

.box .row.header {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  background-color: deeppink;
}

.box .row.content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: violet;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#table-container {
  background-color: yellow;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="row header">
    <p><b>header</b>
      <br />
      <br />(sized to content)</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row content">
    <p>
      <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
    </p>
    <div id="table-container">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Month</th>
            <th>Savings</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>January</td>
            <td>$100</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>February</td>
            <td>$80</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>February</td>
            <td>$80</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>February</td>
            <td>$80</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>February</td>
            <td>$80</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>February</td>
            <td>$80</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>February</td>
            <td>$80</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>February</td>
            <td>$80</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>February</td>
            <td>$80</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>February</td>
            <td>$80</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>February</td>
            <td>$80</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>February</td>
            <td>$80</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>February</td>
            <td>$80</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>February</td>
            <td>$80</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>February</td>
            <td>$80</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>February</td>
            <td>$80</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>February</td>
            <td>$80</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that inside the row that contains the table there are more elements, as the `<p>` in the snippet, and below it is the table container

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, it is enough to change the max-height in table-container to:

```
max-height: 80vh;
```

now you're page will no longer scroll!